# Is there a more efficient way to code this?

Tags: java, arrays, icons, imageicon

```
    final Icon[] landIcons = {
        /* for(int i=0, i<15, i++)
          {
             new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(landNames[i]));
          }
      }*/
       new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(landNames[0])),
       new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(landNames[1])),
       new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(landNames[2])),
       new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(landNames[3])),
       new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(landNames[4])),
       new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(landNames[5])),
       new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(landNames[6])),
       new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(landNames[7])),
       new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(landNames[8])),
       new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(landNames[9])),
       new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(landNames[10])),
       new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(landNames[11])),
       new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(landNames[12])),
       new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(landNames[13])),
       new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(landNames[14]))};
```

I created an array of Icons with an idea in comments to loop each element. I can't say why it doesn't work in the for loop that way. Is there another way to shorten all of this code? Thanks!

Comment: Describe "it doesn't work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn't work bcoz it's illegal syntax.

```
final Icon[] landIcons = {
        for(int i=0, i<15, i++)
          {
             new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(landNames[i]));
          }
      }
```

you can't run loops within array initialization block

use this :

```
  final Icon[] landIcons = new Icon[15];
  for(int i=0, i<landIcons.length , i++)
    {
       landIcons[i] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(landNames[i]));
    }
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! It worked when I changed your suggestion to:                for(int i=0; i < landIcons.length; i++)

Answer (score 0):

You may use a List to hold the items so that you can use a loop to add ImageIcon to that List. If you do need an array, invoke toArray() on that List.